# No root file system - Alternate CD + LVM

Tags: 11.10, cd, lvm, alternate

I am trying to install 11.10 as dual boot with Windows 7.
I have all partitioned well as you can see here:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/42897978@N00/7111180385/

I burned the Alternate CD ISO to a CD.
Boot from it and followed instructions to Partitioning.

There, I configured the LVM partitions as follows:

Volume Group

ubuntu-vg
- Uses Physical Volume /dev/sda7 380GB
- Provides Logical Volume home-lv 60GB
- Provides Logical Volume root-lv 60GB
- Provides Logical Volume swap-lv 6GB

That is all I want (note that my /boot is outside of LVM)

Then when I say that all is Ok and to write it to disk and
continue with the installation, I get the following error.

!! Partition Disks
No root file system
No root file system is defined
Please correct this from the partitioning menu.

What should I fix and how?

I tried issuing the "Revert changes to partitions", but nothing happens.
It seems that the LVM configuration has already been written to the CD.

HELP!!

Comment: which one of those partitions is boot?  a screenshot from a digital camera of your partitioning screen during the installer would be most helpful

Comment: boot is outside of LVM. If you look at my windows partition image (flickr link), it is the 256MB partition inside the Extended partition.

Comment: two primary partition inside extended partition and total number of primary partition is 6 (including extended, where maximum primary partition can be 4). I feel something wrong in partition table. (I am not an expert, this comment is from my past experience)

Comment: I suspect your mountpoints are wrong...that's why I asked for a native screenshot, not a windows partitioning screenshot.  If you don't want help that's fine too.

Comment: @Web-E: no, there are only four primary partitions, three from windows and the extended one.  Remember that the snapshot is from the windows partition utility that does not see the Linux partitions properly.

Comment: @aking1012: chill-out man, I included the windows screenshot in my original question. I am on a new computer and I am looking for my camera drivers... I upload the GParted and LVM screens when I find the camera CD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mount point of root-lv to / and format it with a filesystem.

Also, you don't have to have a separate /boot partition anymore.

Comment: Yes, and I thought that the Alternate CD would allow me to do that, but it does not.  So I guess I should create a Live CD and do it from there installing LVM2 or system-config-lvm?  I created /boot outside before I read that it was not needed out there anymore, can I leave it there or should I delete it and create it inside LVM?  Thanks...

Comment: @Carlos, the alternate cd does allow you to do that.

Comment: How? It goes straight into partitioning and if I go out to the main menu, it continues with the Installation (which I cant because of my problem).  Is there a way to get a console from it_ Thanks.

Comment: @Carlos, after you create the partitions, you need to assign them mount points.

Comment: @Carlos You may need to go into the settings specific to each partition to set a mount point.